# Laravel Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to save 2 different id's to a table, book_id and reader_id,  but I am getting:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Line below it says:

> at Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `book_reader` (`0`) values (?), (?)', array('2', '1'), object(Closure))

Which looks like array is getting the values.

Here's my Controller:

```
function assignbook(Request $request)
{
     $reader_id = $request->input('readers');
     $book_id = $request->input('books');
    DB::table('book_reader')->insert(array('book_id' => $book_id, 'reader_id' => $reader_id));
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans('Book has been successfully assigned to the reader.'));
}
```

And View if it's needed:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')

@section('content')
    <form action="{{url('assignbook')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <h1>Readers details</h1>   
    @foreach ($readers as $reader)
<ul>


    <label>{{$reader->name}}</label>
    <input type='checkbox' value='{{$reader->id}}' name='readers[]'/>


</ul>
        @endforeach
    <h1>Book details</h1>
    @foreach ($books as $book)
<ul>
    <label>{{$book->title}}</label>
    <input type='checkbox' value='{{$book->id}}' name='books[]'/>

</ul>
@endforeach
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" name="submitBtn" value="Assign Book">
    </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: DB::table('...')->insert don"t work that for multiple inserts.
Actually, you pass two array, one with all the N book_id and one with all the N reader_id. You have to pass N array, containing each one two field, one for the book_id and one for the reader_id :)

Comment: `$request->input('readers')` and `$request->input('books')` are arrays?

Comment: yes they are arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, 
reader_id and book_id are array so you need to insert it like this.

```
function assignbook(Request $request)
{
  $reader_id = $request->input('readers');
  $book_id = $request->input('books');
  for($i=0; $i<count($reader_id); $i++)
  {
    DB::table('book_reader')->insert(array('book_id' => $book_id[$i], 'reader_id' => $reader_id[$i]));
  }   
  return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans('Book has been successfully assigned to the reader.'));
}
```

Comment: You overtake me on this one :)
That's the array formation used in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#inserts)